# why do my NSString values get lost in the definition class? is it normal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, persistence, declaration

I'm defining some simple variables in a class of type NSString
one of them is keeping my sqlite database path for example, and so on...
I am initializing that in the AppDelegate , function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
and when I'm trying to see it's value outside this function... it's losing it's value durring runtime, (no I'm not overwrting or anything...)
here's my code...

app.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
.....................
    NSString *site_domain;

    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *databasePath;
..........................
}
```

app.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    databaseName = @"database.sqlite";  
    site_domain=@"http://localhost/webservice";   

         NSLog(@"%@",site_domain);
// inside this function I can use the value, ..if I call whatever function from 
//this function, that function can also use the value...
}

-(void) functionTest {
   NSLog(@"%@",site_domain);
//here the value is lost, it's like it can't reach it's pointer or something...
//puts on a wierd string
}
```

What am i Doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never take ownership of it, your string is getting autoreleased by the auto release pool. In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, try using:

```
site_domain = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://..."];
```

And don't forget to release it int the dealloc method

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [site_domain release];
}
```

Comment: and...of course...it worked.. thank you so much, Objective-C is so confusing sometimes

Comment: If it "worked", then you have fixed a symptom not an actual problem.  Statically allocated strings (@"") *do nothing on retain/release*.

Comment: @bbum good point, but from the follow up comment above I think it is probably not a case of static variables, or there is more to the code that we are not seeing.

Comment: Definitely -- I'd bet that `functionTest` isn't in the same source file / class or something.

Answer (score 1):

> What am i Doing wrong?

You aren't posting enough information. :)

```
//here the value is lost, it's like it can't reach it's pointer or something...
//puts on a wierd string
```

What does that mean?  Show the string.   Is `functionTest` defined in the same source file?  Where is it called from?

Since you are using constant strings (@""), there is no need for retain/release, so that isn't the problem.

Are those really the string values you are using?